# Admin approved file uploads

Tags: 8

I want to allow all authenticated users to upload files, but I want them to be approved first before they're publically viewable.  I'm currently using a single image field for the uploads, that can have unlimited values.

I'm not sure what is a good way of going about this.  Let's say, the user uploads 4 images, which are all shortly after approved.  Then, later, they upload one more image... I still want the first four to be publically viewable, but I don't want the fifth one to be until it's approved.

Also, I am kind of concerned about the fact that the files would be downloadable immediately, as soon as they are uploaded via sites/default/files.  Is this a big deal?  Concerned about copyright violations and such.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you wanted is similar to [commerce file](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_file) module where users can upload file and have configurable settings, where you can limit access duration, number of downloads etc. and about this one `downloadable immediately, as soon as they uploaded via sites/default/files. Is this a big deal?` yes it is big deal once you uploaded it in `sites/default/files` everyone can access it and download anytime without restriction you may violate some regulation. you should upload it outside Drupal where users can't access it via url. Where in `commerce file` already have this settings where you could place your file folder outside Drupal. I am not sure if this is already available in Drupal 8.